# How can I add an index value to a select into a class with LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var result = await db.TestQuestions
                     .Where(t => t.TestId == testId)
                     .Select((t, index) => new GetAllDTO
                     {
                         QuestionUId = t.QuestionUId,
                         QuestionNumber = index
                     }).ToListAsync();
```

and:

```
public class GetAllDTO
{
    public Guid QuestionUId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This is giving me an error when I added the setting of the QuestionNumber.

Comment: 'This is giving me an error...'. What error?

Comment: You should also tag the LINQ provider you're using, for example Linq-To-Entities or Linq-To-Sql. I guess that   it's very important in this case and should also be mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That overloaded version of `Select` is [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in `Linq to Entities`.So you can't use it, instead you can do:

```
var result = await db.TestQuestions
                 .Where(t => t.TestId == testId) 
                 .Select(t => new GetAllDTO
                 {
                     QuestionUId = t.QuestionUId
                 }).ToListAsync();

int i = 0;
foreach(var dto in result)
      dto.QuestionNumber = i++;
```

Or, this should also work:

```
var result = await db.TestQuestions
                 .Where(t => t.TestId == testId)
                 .AsEnumerable()    // notice the AsEnumerable() call
                 .Select((t, index) => new GetAllDTO
                 {
                     QuestionUId = t.QuestionUId,
                     QuestionNumber = index
                 }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I like the AsEnumerable() solution but this gives me an error with .ToListAsync();   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebRole1.Controllers.TestQuestionController.GetAllDTO>' 
does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync'